# multiple arrays value fetching with session

Tags: php, mysql, database

Insert Is Fine But if I select this value from database All Values are fine but single values fetch array problem I don't know how to solve this task. Please  Update this code asap.

This Is Insert Code .....

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sendmessage'])){
    $entermessage = $_POST['teachermessage'];
    $checkbox_user = $_POST['usernameallcheckbx'];
    $arr = implode(',',$checkbox_user);
    //$arr2 = explode(',',$arr);

    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT into usermessages(fromteacher,toparent,messages) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."','$arr','$entermessage')");
    if($insert == 1){
        echo "<h1>successful</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <div style="float:left; width:450px;"><br/><br/>Message: <br/>
    <textarea style="width:400px; height:300px;" name="teachermessage"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sendmessage" /></div>
    <div style="float:left; with:200px; padding-top:55px;">
    <table>
    <tr>    
    <?php 
    $select_query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register_user WHERE teacher='$teachername'");
while($chckbx=mysql_fetch_array($select_query1))
    {
        ?>
        <td><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='usernameallcheckbx[]' value=". $chckbx['userid']." />"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $chckbx['parent_fname']." ".$chckbx['parent_lname']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>

</table>
</div>
</form>
```

And This Is Select Code....

```
<h2>Messages</h2>

<?php 
$select_query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usermessages");
$fetch= mysql_fetch_array($select_query3);
$data=$fetch['toparent'];
$arr=explode(',',$data);
//$userids=explode(',',$data);
$sessionshow=$_SESSION['userid'];
$userids=in_array("$sessionshow",$arr);

$select_query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usermessages WHERE toparent in ('$userids')='".$_SESSION['userid']."'"); 


?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <th>Teacher Name</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($fetch_name2=mysql_fetch_array($select_query2))
        {   
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$fetch_data=$fetch_name2['fromteacher']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$fetch_data=$fetch_name2['messages']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
?>                                   
</table>
```

Comment: `$userids` is just `true` or `false`. Why are you using that in `WHERE toparent in ('$userids')`? What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Your schema is poorly designed. Putting a comma-separated list in `toparent` makes matching that column really hard. You can't use `IN` to match individual values like that, it will try to compare the entire list as a string.

Comment: Hi, Userid is username and i am trying to single values fetch from database. I insert values using checkbox arrays. and implode function use but if i select query use all values fetch but i need only session value fetch.

Comment: I don't understand. You're setting `$userids = in_array($sessionshow, $arr);` That just returns `true` or `false` depending on whether `$sessionshow` is in `$arr`.

Comment: I also don't understand your first `SELECT` query. You're just fetching one random row from `SELECT * FROM usermessage`.

Answer (score 0):

I have only put this as an answer to show some incorrect code - remove fetch data from your loop as it doesn't do anything

```
while($fetch_name2=mysql_fetch_array($select_query2))
{   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch_name2['fromteacher']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch_name2['messages']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

even better is use of a HEREDOC:

```
while($fetch_name2=mysql_fetch_array($select_query2))
{   
    echo <<<EOF
<tr>
   <td>{$fetch_name2['fromteacher']}</td>
   <td>{$fetch_name2['messages']}</td>
</tr>
EOF;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Saying that you know it's not an answer doesn't excuse it. What's so hard about posting a comment that says "Remove the assignments to `$fetch_data`, they're not useful."?

Comment: Expanded answer also shows better method - stop being picky :-)

Answer (score 0):

I really can't figure out what you're trying to do, but maybe this is the query you want:

```
SELECT * FROM usermessages WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$sessionshow', toparent)
```

[`FIND_IN_SET(str, strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) searches the comma-separated list in `strlist` for an element that equals `str`, and returns the position in the list; if it's not found it returns `0`, which counts as `false`.

I can't see any purpose to any of the code that uses `$select_query3`.